# Can eigenvalues of the density matrix in the Lindblad equation be negative?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, probability, density-operator, eigenvalue

Can the *density matrix* in the Lindblad equation for an *open mixed* quantum system have (real part) negative eigenvalues?

Comment: Have you read the corresponding [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindbladian) article already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The density matrix by definition is a [positive semi-definite matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix). It therefore has *real positive eigenvalues*.

Physically, these eigenvalues correspond to the probability $p_i$ of being in one of the pure eigenstates $|\phi_i\rangle$ [according to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#Definition_and_motivation)

$$\rho = \sum_i p_i |\phi_i\rangle\langle \phi_i|.$$

**Clarification in response to the comments**

The above answer only uses the definition of the density matrix. Positive semi-definiteness of $\rho$ is a very basic property which follows from its probability interpretation.

The above also allows for mixed states. As @ZeroTheHero states, a pure state would be the case where one of the $p_i=1$, such that $\rho=|\phi_i\rangle\langle \phi_i|$.

According to the comments, the OP may contain a second question, which is related to the dynamics generated by the Lindblad equation. Indeed, the [Lindblad equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindbladian) manifestly conserves positive semi-definiteness of the density matrix. It is also trace preserving, since another important property of the density matrix is that the probabilities $p_i$ sum to 1.

Note that the Lindblad equation is particularly nice because of this property. While it usually is derived using multiple approximations, it produces a fully consistent density matrix at all times of the dynamics. This is not the case for many other ways to treat open system dynamics. E.g. the [Redfield equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redfield_equation) contains less approximations, but does not generate positive time evolution.

Comment: I think the question is whether the dynamics dictated by the Lindblad equation conserve the PSDness of the matrix.

Comment: I am not talking about the density matrix in a pure state, rather in an open mixed state. You are referring to a pure state.

Comment: @proton indeed taking decoherence and entanglement to environment, dissipation, and fluctuations into account, the density matrix seems to be re-defined, but I cannot find any references or answer somewhere else.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi (Am I misunderstanding your comment?) The expression of $\rho$ given in the answer is for a mixed state.  A pure state would have one $p_i=1$ and all the others $0$.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi See edit. Also +1 to ZeroTheHero's comment. I've further added an explanation in case proton's comment is correct, I find the OP somewhat unclear in this regard.